# GRASS i.landsat.toar returns empty raster

Tags: grass-gis, landsat

I am trying to use the GRASS module i.landsat.toar.

Currently the files created are empty and it spits out:

[image]

So it seems that it is not picking up something?  The location is set to the extent of the landsat image.  Does anyone have an idea where I am going wrong?

Becky

Comment: Could you please describe exactly how you try to use the module?

Comment: Sorry, since writing this post I have solved the problem by using the MTLold file that comes with the landsat imagery.  The program appeared not to be able to read the more recent MTL version.

Comment: Which GRASS GIS version do you use? The newer versions support both the old as well as the new "MTL" metadata files.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris I think it should be possible for you to craft an answer of a few sentences to say basically what you have commented.  By providing an answer you can not only potentially earn reputation but you can help the asker and future readers better understand the historical nature of the question and currency of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The original question could have been more complete, if the exact command instructed would have been posted.  As well, the exact type of Landsat product, and the metadata file in question.

Anyhow, from the screenshot, one can conclude that the original poster tried to work on Landsat7 bands. Taking into account the date when the question was posted, it is likely that the version of GRASS used, was version 6.4.

Support for the "new" --at the time-- type of metadata files (MTL), was added:

- for GRASS 6.4, see [revision 54844](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/changeset/54844) on 02/02/13 (change details: [Changes in  grass/branches/releasebranch_6_4/imagery/i.landsat.toar/landsat_met.c [53339:54844]](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/changeset?new=54844%40grass%2Fbranches%2Freleasebranch_6_4%2Fimagery%2Fi.landsat.toar%2Flandsat_met.c&old=53339%40grass%2Fbranches%2Freleasebranch_6_4%2Fimagery%2Fi.landsat.toar%2Flandsat_met.c) -- **note, this happened 1 day after the question was posted!**
- for GRASS 7, around the time of [revision 57936](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/changeset/57936) (see also: [Changes in grass/trunk/imagery/i.landsat.toar [57933:57936]](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/changeset/57936/grass/trunk/imagery/i.landsat.toar?old=57933&old_path=grass%2Ftrunk%2Fimagery%2Fi.landsat.toar#file7)) in the module's code for handling metadata. That was April 2014, which is about 2 months after the date when the question was posted.

Comment: Please, accept this answer so as to help future readers to understand better the historical nature of the question. In addition, this example emphasizes the speed with which things can roll in an open source project. In case the answer won't be accepted within reasonable time --given it is an old question and, thus, of less "usage" interest-- I kindly ask (and will act upon via a flag) for closing it.